# Indexerror: list index out of range/numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am really
 new to python. I am getiing an error stating Indexerror list index out of range. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance .
Edit 1

```
x = np.array([10,0])
Phi = np.array([[ 1.  ,  0.01],
            [ 0.  ,  1.  ]])
Gamma = np.array([[ 0.0001048 ],
              [ 0.02096094]])
Z = np.array([[ 0.0001048 ],
          [ 0.02096094]])
wd = 0
u_new = 0
x1d = 0
x2d = 0
xd = [[0 for col in range(len(x))] for row in range(1000)]
xd[0][0] = 10
xd[1][0] = 0
k = 10
DistPeriodNo1 = 500
FirstPeriod = 1
k=k+1 #Update PeriodNo(so PeriodNo is now equal to No. of current period)
if (k == 100):  #If maximum value of PeriodNo is reached,
    k = 11  #set it to 1
    DistPeriodNo1 = random.randint(11,99) 

if (FirstPeriod == 0):  

    if (k == DistPeriodNo1):    
        wd = random.randint(-1,1)
    else:
        wd = 0
    xd[0][k] = Phi*xd[0][k-1] - Gamma*u_new + Z*wd
    # >>indexerror list index out of range
    xd[1][k] = Phi*xd[1][k-1] - Gamma*u_new + Z*wd
    x1d = xd[0][k]
    x2d = xd[1][k]
```

Comment: You can help us help you if add the entire [stack trace](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) in the question.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "if ***you*** add"

Comment: i am reallz now to this...can yoou tell me how to add a stack trace? i know this is very dumb. I am sorry.

Comment: Copy the whole error text in the question, there is additional info there that can be useful like line numbers.

Comment: By the way, I can't reproduce the error, your code runs ok in my PC.

Comment: You should paste the exact traceback (error info) you read after trying to run this code. Edit: already answered by elyase.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like this is your full code.  Was there a loop somewhere between `k = 10` and `k=k+1`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the comments about tracebacks (stack traces): running the following

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [True, False]
print(a[2])
print(b[2])
```

produces one answer and one traceback.

```
>>> 
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\python34\tem.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(b[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The traceback shows what line and what code raised the error.  People were asking you to copy the last 4 line and paste them into your question (by editing it).